SpringBoot でログイン画面がうまくいかない
Spring Boot の勉強を最近始めたものです。 Spring Boot にて、ログイン画面を作りたいのですが、今は以下の記事のコードを丸コピして動作確認しようとしています。 しかし、データベースに登録されたユーザーは、パスワードを入力するのもログインに失敗します。 ソースコード自体に問題みたいですが、色々調べましたが自分の方では少々限界が来ています。
以下が java、SpringBoot の種類、参考記事です。
java バージョン:17
spring boot バージョン: 3.3.0
参考記事：SpringSecurity+BCrypt+PostgreSQL でログイン機能実装
以上、よろしくお願いします。
